# Xamarin get webservice with parameter

Tags: json, xamarin, get

i am new with xamarin. I want to add some json data with get web service. I try like following:

```
 var response = await client.GetAsync("myurl" + "?applicationid=" + 
    applicationId + "?siteid=" + siteId + "?userid=" + userId");
 string responseJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
 Debug.WriteLine("response:>" + responseJson);
```

But code not executed after get method.

please anyone help me.
Thanks in advance.  :)

Comment: Finally got the solution, pass the values with the url itself.

     var response = await 
      client.GetAsync("mybaseurl"+"/applicationid/"1"/siteid/"5"/userid/"+25");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the solution, pass the values with the url itself. 
var response = await client.GetAsync("mybaseurl"+"/applicationid/"1"/siteid/"5"/u‌​serid/"+25");